# What algorithm can i use to refine image selection mask?

Tags: android, c++, algorithm, opencv, image-processing

I need an algorithm to be able to contrast detect edges in a photo.

Users will roughly paint the mask over an object in an image with their fingers on android phone and then i want to refine the selection mask with the code that detects the edges and adjusts the mask to the edges.

Comment: Can you tells what you have tried, or where you are at?

Comment: Well i haven't got anywhere yet, still searching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please read about hough transform also canny and you can decide which are better/
this not an easy thing to do. 
i would suggest you try to understand how do they work with matlab first this is very C-like language.

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/canny_detector/canny_detector.html